# Material-UI Checkbox "jumps" in grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The following grid structure in my Material-UI collapsible is my desired layout:

[Desired grid layout](https://ibb.co/ByVx5B2)

I already tried changing the layout by playing with the flex-direction.

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-nobel-ov48j

When I click on the checkboxes, the last checkbox tends to "jump" from its position away and stacks itself under the other two ones. At the moment I can't find the reason why. You can see the result of this behaviour on this picture:

[Undesired grid layout](https://ibb.co/jwp4S99)

On smaller screens this behaviour would be okay but especially on larger screens I want the two columns layout where the first one contains two checkboxes and the second contains the third one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Radosław Cybulski: Thank you for your help. With your code and some modifications I was able to get it to work. You don't have to specify *direction="row"* because it is the default settting.

Now it looks like this:

```
<ExpansionPanelDetails className={classes.details}>
    <Typography paragraph>
      Example text
    </Typography>
    <Grid container justify="space-between">
        <Grid container item xs={6} md={3}>
            <Grid
                container
                item
                style={{
                    alignItems: "center",
                    paddingBottom: "8px",
                }}
            >
                <Grid
                    item
                    xs={6}
                    style={{
                        textAlign: "right",
                        paddingRight: "16px",
                    }}
                >
                    Text Supervisor
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <CustomCheckBox employeePosition="supervisor" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid
                container
                item
                style={{ alignItems: "center" }}
            >
                <Grid
                    item
                    xs={6}
                    style={{
                        textAlign: "right",
                        paddingRight: "16px",
                    }}
                >
                    Text Employee
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <CustomCheckBox employeePosition="employee" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <Grid
            container
            item
            xs={6}
            md={3}
            style={{ alignContent: "center" }}
            direction="row"
        >
            <Grid
                container
                item
                style={{ alignItems: "center" }}
            >
                <Grid
                    item
                    xs={6}
                    style={{
                        textAlign: "right",
                        paddingRight: "16px",
                    }}
                >
                    {useTranslation("employee")}
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <CustomCheckBox employeePosition="employee" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Hidden smDown>
            <Grid container item md={6} />
        </Hidden>
    </Grid>
</ExpansionPanelDetails>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  <ExpansionPanelDetails className={classes.details}>
    <Typography paragraph>Exmaple text</Typography>
    <Grid container justify="space-between" direction="row">
      <Grid container item justify="space-between" xs={6}>
        <Grid container item style={{ alignItems: "center" }} direction="row">
          <Grid item xs={6}>Text Supervisor</Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <CustomCheckBox employeePosition="supervisor" />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container item style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
          <Grid item xs={6}>Text Employee</Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <CustomCheckBox employeePosition="employee" />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>

      <Grid container item xs={6} style={{ alignContent: "center" }} direction="row">
        <Grid container item style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
          <Grid item xs={6}>Text Employee</Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <CustomCheckBox employeePosition="employee" />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </ExpansionPanelDetails>
```

I'm rather new to this js / material-ui / react thing, so you probably might improve it even further.